# Can't trace the problem in BST delete function

Tags: go, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I can't trace the mistake in my logic in BST delete function in Go.

```
func delete(d *Node, v int) {
if d == nil {
    fmt.Println("The tree is empty")
}
if v < d.key {
    delete(d.left, v)
} else if v > d.key {
    delete(d.right, v)
} else if v == d.key {
    if d.right == nil && d.left == nil {
        d = nil
    } else {
        if d.left == nil && d.right != nil {
            d.key= d.right.key
            delete(d.right,d.key)


        } else if d.right == nil && d.left != nil {
            d.key= d.left.key
            delete(d.left,d.key)
        }else{
        min := minvalue(d.right)
        d.key = min.key
        delete(d.right, min.key)
    }
    }
}
}
```

[The output shouldn't contain 4 but the result is instead showing 6 two times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Oz4.png)

The expected output is 5 6, but it's showing 4 6 6

Comment: Post a [mcve].  Show the declaration of `Node` and the input that produces the results described in the question.

Comment: `if d == nil {` don't *just* print, but make sure to `return` as well.

Comment: FYI with `d = d.right` and `d = d.left` you're just updating the `d`'s *pointer*, you're *not* updating the value to which `d` points to. So the `*Node` outside of `delete` remains unchanged.

Comment: I tried to.    d.key=d.right.key   delete (d.right,d.right.key)  ...Still it's not working ..

Answer (score 1):

As several have noted in the comments, you should provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which helps people avoid wasting time on simple misunderstandings.

In this case, though, it's pretty obvious what you have done wrong—at least, at the first layer.  (There may be more, depending on what you intend to do with these trees.)

Consider the following function:

```
func setToNil(p *int) {
    p = nil
}
```

Let's use this from a `main`:

```
func main() {
    x := 3
    px := &x
    fmt.Println("before: x =", x, "px =", px)
    setToNil(px)
    fmt.Println("after: x =", x, "px =", px)
}
```

[(Complete version on the Go playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/_Aq6n9FNJ38)

What do you expect this program to do?  Try it out: did it do what you expected?  Why, or why not?  If not, what about this variant:

```
func setToTheAnswer(i int) {
    i = 42
}

func main() {
    x := 3
    fmt.Println("before: x =", x)
    setToTheAnswer(x)
    fmt.Println("after: x =", x)
}
```

Fill in the rest and try it out.  Why didn't `x` change?  (Should it have changed?  If you think so, *why* do you think so?  The language definition says that it *should not*.)

Now, compare that to this version:

```
func setToTheAnswer(p *int) {
    *p = 42
}

func setToNil(q **int) {
    *q = nil
}

func main() {
    x := 3
    px := &x
    fmt.Println("before: x =", x, "px =", px)
    setToTheAnswer(px)
    setToNil(&px)             // note the & in front of px
    fmt.Println("after: x =", x, "px =", px)
}
```

What will this version do?  [Try it on the playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/aXa4n0dPqQt)

#### With that in mind, think about your variable `d`

Your function:

```
func delete(d *Node, v int) {
    // ...
}
```

takes a parameter named `d` of type `pointer to Node` (and `v` of type `int` of course).  If you change `d` in `delete`, that has no effect on any `* Node` variable in any caller, because `d` is a *copy* of this pointer-to-Node.  You can change **`*d`** to change the `Node` to which the caller's pointer points, but you cannot change the caller's pointer.

There are multiple different ways to fix this.  For instance, instead of taking a `d *Node` you might take a different object that *contains* a `root *Node` pointer, or you might take a `pd **Node` so that you can update a `d *Node` in the caller.  Which is the right way?  That's up to you.